# Get the time value of an hour ago on Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to get an `hour` ago `hour` value of current `time` in `google sheets`.

For example

```
TEXT(NOW(),"DDHH")
```

> returns current date+hour value (2500, if its 25th, midnight)

**can I get 2423 instead using formula?**

just putting `-1` works for most of hours but fails at midnight (it `returns 2499`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
=TEXT(NOW()-1/24,"DDHH")
```

In date notation 1 is one day and one hour is 1/24 of a day.

It works for me:

[image]

(note that I use ; instead of comma as I have polish settings in my spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

Adding -1 at the end of the formula will return 2499 because it will treat it like integer 2500 - 1. Adding -1 after NOW() will return 2400 because it will subtract 1 as 1 day. You can try this formula to subtract an hour.

```
=TEXT(NOW()-(1/24),"DDHH")
```